# intelliJ giving me a 'settings synchronization failed' error message

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I'm having a problem setting up a grails application using intelliJ. I went to `file->Project Structure`, in intelliJ, and made the `IDEA IU-129.713(java version "1.7.0_10")` as the project SDK.

http://snag.gy/4esPt.jpg

Soon as I clicked okay, I got a 'settings synchronization failed' error message (seen on right side of image).

http://snag.gy/wQN1S.jpg

did I add the wrong project SDK? or is something else the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't project sdk be your JDK location. In your case I see it is in `C:\Program Files\java\jdk....`?

Comment: i tried adding the regular java JDK, still get same message http://snag.gy/id1sV.jpg

Comment: http://snag.gy/repd0.jpg

Comment: Try setting your language level to Java 7, not 8, and also check that you have a JAVA_HOME environment variable set correctly. I'm not sure these will help, but I have a hunch that it might.

Comment: I can't see the images: are they still working?